# How to trap an error in C++ when __try __except can't

Tags: c++, error-handling, system-error

I have code that uses a 3rd party library.

That library throws the occasional Access Violation exception.  A basic try/catch didn't catch the error, and the program would hard crash.

I was able to use a __try __except instead, to catch the error, log it, and then gracefully exit the program.

The 3rd party has just updated their library, and now a small subset of the records that were causing the access violation errors just dies in production with "[program name] has stopped working"

In Visual Studio, when stepping thru I get "Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in [program name]."

I've updated my __except statement to catch everything (or so I believe), and it still happens.

Original __except:

```
__except (eps = GetExceptionInformation(), ((GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION) 
              ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER 
              : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)) {
        sprintf("error message");
        result = 99;
}
```

New __except:

```
__except (eps = GetExceptionInformation(), ((1 == 1)
              ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER 
              : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)) {
        sprintf("error message");
        result = 99;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a friendly FYI, the first expression in your exception filter `eps = GetExceptionInformation()` appears to be unused.

Also, if you want to catch all exceptions then `__except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)` should be all you need. Although I would only recommend that for debugging purposes.

If this does not catch your exception, it is possible that the library is trying to handle the exception itself and something funky is going on in the library itself. I would check with the provider of the library and ask if this is a known issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
same results as the other two.  I've asked the 3rd party, but their time frames tend to be too long for fixes, which is why I had to handle their access violations to begin with.

Comment: Do you have access to their symbols and source code? Would you be able to actually debug it on their end to figure out how the exception is happening? If the exception is never getting caught even with __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) then my hunch is that the library is attempting to handle the exception so your code never actually gets it.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access.  I have a question out to their developers citing the behavior with the example record, and the version numbers from before/after the new behavior,  Sounds like I might be stuck until I hear back.  Thank you for your help.